# Save changed NSManagmentObject to core data Fails

Tags: core-data, restkit

Could you please help me we my problem. I have service wich cache all requests results to core data. I use RestKit for do that. All work fine except saving. Then i try change some property in object and then save it NSManagedObjectContext save method done with out errore but if i look in this object after saving changes i see:

```
<User: 0xcedf910> (entity: User; id: 0xcede9f0 <x-coredata://904DBCDF-F1CF-4F2B-B173-2994FE47DEC8/User/p1800> ; data: <fault>)
```

And then try to get data from over object i get fault:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xcedbce0 <x-coredata://904DBCDF-F1CF-4F2B-B173-2994FE47DEC8/User/p1722>
```

Code for fetching objects:

```
[objectManager.objectStore objectsForResourcePath:path]
```

Could any help with it? Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be bug in NSManagedObjectContext save in RestKit

Answer (score 0):

NSObjectInaccessibleException, means just that.

It's possible that you created an NSManagedObject and put it in the context, possibly saved a reference to it somewhere. Then it was removed from the context and wasn't saved and you tried to access it again.

Comment: I do one fetch requet [objectManager.objectStore objectsForResourcePath:path] and then change one property in some object returned from request. And then do save [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore save];. After that <User: 0xcedf910> (entity: User; id: 0xcede9f0 <x-coredata://904DBCDF-F1CF-4F2B-B173-2994FE47DEC8/User/p1800> ; data: <fault>) and if i try get data from any object returned from this fetch request it crach(